# Best practice for setting path when deploying python code to different servers

Tags: python, path

Ubuntu 20.04 
Python 3.8.5

Currently I am setting paths as follows

```
cwd = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
given_path = '../../project1-datas/file.csv'
file_path = os.path.join(cwd, given_path)
```

This correctly saves csv files to correct path which is two directories both cwd.

However when I deploy this to my development server(which has different folder path) I need to manually change `given_path` variable.

Is there a way to change this manual change to automatic or is it better to simply create folder architecture exactly the same so there is no need to change `given_path` variable. (But if I am deploying to multiple servers or different users are using my code it doesn't seem to be very efficient.)

Answer (score 1):

Don't store your data files in the same directory as your Python source. Instead, put them in a project-specific subdirectory of `/usr/share` or `/usr/local/share` (depending on whether you use `/usr` or `/usr/local` for the rest of your files).

Comment: my given path is actually `../../project1-datas/files.csv` isn't datas folder then project-specific subdirectory?

Comment: My point is that your script shouldn't have to use `os.path.dirname` to determine the absolute path your `given_path` is relative to.  Make it something you know when you *install* the code, without having to wait until you *run* the code.